# Query results change after making an PK Clustered

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, sql-server-2000

In a new mission, I am faced with a SQL Server 2000 :( where I found plenty of large tables without any clustered index. So I suggested changing that. When testing, we found - and double checked - that at least one query was not returning the same result when the PK index was clustered and when it was not.
I know the query is ugly; it is generated by the GUI where the user can select fields and conditions for a custom report. Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT   p.*, pcc.PatentCostCentreLink_pk, pcc.Client_fk, 
                  pcc.Division_fk, pcc.CostCentre_fk, pcc.Reference, pcc.DecisionMaker
FROM            dbo.Patent AS p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PatentCostCentreLink AS pcc ON p.Patent_pk = pcc.Patent_fk
WHERE (pcc.Client_fk = 2787) AND (pcc.Division_fk IS NULL)  
AND (pcc.CostCentre_fk = 20066) AND (pcc.Reference LIKE 'P1049%')
```

My question is: with the **same tables** - except for changing 1 PK from `non-clustered` to `clustered` - why/how is it possible that the **same query** returns different result sets ? (23 rows with non clustered index, 1 row with clustered index).
Remarks about the nonsense in the query are useless. I *know* it's bad.

*Note*: the changed index is PK_PatentCostCentreLink, on dbo.PatentCostCentreLink.PatentCostCentreLink_pk (identity column).

*Note2*: when removing the `DISTINCT` or changing the `JOIN` to `INNER` then both databases return the same result (23 rows), as expected. But has I mentioned, that's is another question.

Comment: Does `PatentCostCentreLink.PatentCostCentreLink_pk` contain `NULL` values?

Comment: @lad2025 PatentCostCentreLink.PatentCostCentreLink_pk field does not contain `NULL`s if that is you question

Comment: Provide execution plans for clustered/non-clustered query

Answer (score 1):

I would check a couple of things:

1. Make sure you use the latest service pack / hotfix available. AFAIR, it should be 8.0.2253, unless your company has extended support access or whatever it was back then. Check [SQL Server Builds](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com.au/#sql2000) for details.
2. Make sure that your data is not corrupted. I can't recall the details now, but `dbcc checkdb()` command on 2000 version misses some discrepancies, so it would be better to attach / restore the database on the 2005 instance and checking it there.
3. Perform any maintenance that might affect this: rebuilding indices, updating statistics, etc.

Semantically, this query will result in `inner` rather than `outer` join (the `WHERE` part contains conditions for outer table), so there can be no reasonable explanation for this behaviour. So, unless anything mentioned above will help, chances are you've hit some heap-related bug that nobody will fix... Time for upgrade? :)

Comment: Time for upgrade...I wish ! We have 8.0.2039 which seems to be the latest version for SS2K. I feel deprived of all my tricks and recent knowledge, and most stuff you find on internet does NOT work with SS2K.
Your idea to restore to a more recent server is a good one. I think there is a 2012 one somewhere here. Thx

Comment: The upgrade is also slowed by the fact the db uses some custom DLL written in VB6, which does not seem to be supported in later versions.

Comment: @iDevlop, I'm afraid it's impossible to restore 2000 backup directly on 2012 server, you will need a 2005 or 2008 instance (2008 R2 might not work). Microsoft usually tends to keep database format compatibility for 2 releases back from the current, so oldest backup you can restore on 2012 will have to come from 2005 instance.